Entry exit signals showing on next to real candle
if exit_trade == "exit_CE"
    strategy.exit("CE-Ex", from_entry = "CE", limit = open)

plotshape(exit_trade == "exit_CE", title="Exit CE", location=location.top, color=color.orange, style=shape.triangledown, text="Exit CE")

I am using the above code in my strategy and have applied the same condition for strategy.exit and for plotshape functions.
The plotshape function showing signal on correct candle but strategy.exit function shifting signal one or two candles right to the actual candle.

Why is this happening and how do I solve it?

Your profit limit is open, but only when exit_trade == "exit_CE"
Separate your exit rule from your profit, and use comments to debug.
if strategy.position_size > 0
    strategy.exit(
      id             = "CE-Ex",
      from_entry     = "CE",
      limit          = open,
      comment_profit = 'TP')

if exit_trade == "exit_CE"
    strategy.close(
      'Long',
      comment        = 'exit_CE')


Thanks, It worked for me after a little modification.
One more help I need, In strategy tester in list of trades entry and exit price is close price of that candle but I need open price of candle because entry and exit signals are generating at the time of candle opening.

Your script will be run when a candle is closed (the last data has arrived and no more data will be added to the candle). Then you decide to Enter/Exit and you issue the necessary command to do that.
Many people have mainly crypto in their head where the markets are open 24/7 but think of ETFs which close on Friday and open on Monday. If the Friday candle has been closed, the market is closed until Monday, there is no way the broker would execute an Exit order until Monday. If you are lucky with your broker, they will take your order as pending, and will execute it on Monday market opening.
Also, you are executing your script on Tradingview's broker emulator and that emulator has a way of working. If you issue an Enter/Exit order, it will executed on the next tick when the next price change comes in from the "broker", in case of historical bars, that will be Tradingview's broker emulator. If a candle has been closed then the next tick can only come in from the next candle, which might be hours or days ahead.
So the next possible time the Enter/Exit command can be executed is the next candle's first tick, this is why Tradingview shows the Exit on the next candle. Also, note, that an "Exit" order is a pending order by nature, even if it is immediately executed. To exit from a positions there has to be a tick coming in from the broker where the exit can be executed on. (Imagine a very-very illiquid security. It is highly possible that when you want to exit by selling, there won't be any buyer at all. Then you would have to wait until a buyer comes in and matches with your sell offer).
To mitigate the issue a bit, try adding this to the strategy() definition in your script:
process_orders_on_close = true

But, say, you trade SPY, and when you get an Exit signal on Tradingview it will be already too late for you to do anything with your broker as it will be already closed for the day (closing at 4PM EST).
All the above won't solve the issue with the last candle, which is a realtime candle that behaves very differently compared to historical bars.
